# Где почитать о том, как функционирует ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Пересмотрел множество источников в поисках объяснения, как работает MVC.  Очень много деталей, но в общую картину их сложить оказывается невозможно - множество объектов и классов, работа которых подробно разъясняется, но никогда не объясняется, откуда они берутся, кто их создаёт, множество интерфейсов, которые надо реализовать и функций, которые должны быть override, но никогда не объясняется кто и когда их вызывает и пр. Видны отдельные конструкции, выступающие за пределы чёрного ящика и можно их модифицировать и заменять, но как их использует запрятанный в ящике механизм остаётся мистической загадкой. Крайне желательно иметь бы об это ну хоть какое-то очень общее понятие, чтобы сложить в систему массу мелких знаний об отдельных элементах, тогда бы и мелкие значительно лучше понимались бы.

Вот, казалось бы, близкая к подобного рода объяснениям статья - <a href="http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruwebapps/archive/2011/11/16/asp-net-mvc-3-3-asp-net-mvc.aspx" >"Основы выполнения приложения MVC"</a>. Начинаю чтение и в первой строчке же читаю: "Запросы к приложению проходят через HTTP-модуль UrlRoutingModule, обрабатывающий запрос и отправляющий его по соответствующему маршруту"

Возможно, человек подготовленный сразу понимает, о чём речь. Для меня же тут масса непреодолимых препятствий:

1. "запросом" наверное называется строка вида "http://host/controller/action".?
2. о том, что такое "модуль UrlRoutingModule" и его функциональности можно прочесть, но откуда вдруг он взялся из небытия? Кто его создавал и кто вызывает его функции, определяет их последовательность и пр.?
3. есть ещё какие-то модули? Модули чего? Какую подсистему они образуют?
4. что такое "проходят через модуль". Что-то куда-то подали на вход и получили в ответ что? Если вызов - то чего. Уже имеющегося объекта? Создали новый?
5. что означает "запрос отправлен по существующему маршруту". Создали новый контроллер и вызвали соответствующее действие?

ну и т.д. Я не то, чтобы не совсем понимал всего этого, но вместо ясной картины складывается цепь догадок, рано или поздно заводящая в тупик. Всё, дальше двигаться нельзя. Это, как если бы я искал ответа на вопрос как работает автомобиль и получал только надо нажать вот эту штуковину, а вот эту фиговинку повернуть и тогда он едет и бибикает.

Где поискать, на русском или английском, какие-то разъяснения, чтобы сдвинуться с этой мёртвой точки? Как увидеть лес за всеми деревьями?

Comment: Как вариант, вы можете посмотреть исходный код asp.net mvc и разобраться во всём самому :)

Comment: > "запросом" наверное называется строка вида "http://host/controller/action".?

Не совсем, набор заголовков, куда входят хост (http://host), URI (/controller/action). Подробнее в любом документе о http-запросах

> О том, что такое "модуль UrlRoutingModule" и его функциональности можно прочесть, но откуда вдруг он взялся из небытия? Кто его создавал и кто вызывает его функции, определяет их последовательность и пр.?

Предположу, что приложение целиком (сам ASP).

> что означает "запрос отправлен по существующему маршруту". Создали новый контроллер и вызвали соответствующее действие?

да

Comment: Etki, ....Предположу, что приложение целиком (сам ASP)

Модуль - это программная часть работающая на IIS, т.е. это надстройки http сервера IIS

Answer (score 1):

А вы уверены, что надо опускать вплоть до таких деталей?

Можно прочитать две тысячи страниц о сетях, что бы понимать как и куда приходят запросы. Можно прочитать две тысячи страниц об архитектуре компьютера, что бы понимать, как работает компьютер во всех деталях. Можно прочитать пару тысяч страниц по операционным системам, что бы понимать: как они работают; как происходят вызовы программ в них; как взаимодействуют компоненты. Можно изучить вдоль и поперек C#, интерпретаторы и компиляторы(1,5 тысяч страниц), и модель MVC. Можно прочитать про работу серверов и наращивание производительности.

И через три, а скорее даже пять лет понять, что все это только ради того, что бы разобраться в написание простого ASP.NET MVC приложения, которое вы бы написали и без этого всего. Многие вещи специально прячутся в черный ящик. Водить машину можно и без подробнейшего изучения всех тонкостей работы двигатели, встроенной электроники и прочих элементов.

На вашем месте я бы ограничился прочтением о клиент-серверной трехуровневой(трехзвенной) архитектуре, как сервер обрабатывает URI запросы, HTTP запросах и простейшей модели MVC. Это ответит на большинство вопросов. Остальное принять как должное и усложнение простой архитектуры путем добавления функциональности, и о чем можно почитать на досуге.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет
[Lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)